# PHP 5.3.5 PDO FETCH_OBJ memory leak?

Tags: php, memory, pdo, memory-leaks

I'm currently developing an application in PHP which uses PDO. I'm writing an import which reads in a CSV file, checks the database for a record, and updates, deletes, etc....

Something which I've noticed is the memory being used by this script seems very high and it seems like it could be to do with the way I'm executing the query. see below for example query which is executed for each line in the CSV:

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM company WHERE id = 1";
$sth = $this->prepare($qry);
$sth->execute();
$sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_INTO, new Company());
$sth->fetch();
```

for the above memory_get_peak_usage() = 6291456

When using the below:

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM company WHERE id = 1";
$sth = $this->prepare($qry);
$sth->execute();
$sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "Company");
$sth->fetch();
```

for the above memory_get_peak_usage() = 524288

As you can see the difference is fairly big.

I guess I've 3 questions..

1. Is there a memory leak when using PDO::FETCH_OBJ in PHP 5.3.5?
2. Is there any difference between using FETCH_CLASS as opposed to FETCH_OBJ?
3. Has anyone else experienced the same issue?

Company Class is simple:

```
class Company {
    function __construct(){}
    /**classvars**/
    public $_tablename = 'company';
    public $transient;
    public $id;
    public $name;
    /**endclassvars**/
}
```

Comment: @MikeB: But the question he's asking is why the drastic difference.

Comment: @Martin You propably misunderstood `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`. See my answer

Comment: @MikeB Contents of the Company class has nothing to do with it... He's instantiating a company object either way. It doesn't matter what the Company class *does*, because it's doing the same thing in both cases.

Comment: Sorry, I had put the wrong code in.. Its not PDO::FETCH_OBJ, what I have is PDO::FETCH_INTO. Question still remains. I've edited my post

Comment: @MikeB - My class has nothing but a constructor and variables that correspond to the fields in the database

Comment: If you suspect there might be a memory leak in 5.3.5, then the first solution you should have tried is to update to the latest patch release, currently 5.3.21. There have been a *lot* of bugs and security issues fixed between 5.3.5 and 5.3.21. You really should keep your software patched up to date anyway.

Comment: @Martin What does `var_dump($this->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT));` say?

Comment: @hek2mgl - looks like its just returning : bool(false) .

Comment: @Martin Are you using the PDO_MySQL driver?

Comment: I believe so:
PDO


PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => mysql

pdo_mysql

Comment: Ok. I will try to reproduce using some simulated data. Will give you a feedback. You could search the php bug database during this. I've done so but nothing found yet. but there are a lot ;)

Comment: Does it behave the same when you are using PHP5.2 or PHP5.4?

Comment: I don't know as of yet. I've just noticed this on my system which has 5.3.5 . As @SDC has pointed out below, it does look like a lot of PDO stuff has been updated since this version. I will have to upgrade and try out my scripts again. I don't really want to go though my DAO's and update these functions :P Thanks very much for your input, appreciated!

Comment: Yes you should. I've tested with PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 and can see no problem. The FETCH_CLASS used 24 bytes more memory :) (because of the second param I assume)

Comment: hmm.. I've upgraded my ubuntu PHP to version: 5.4.9. Although the memory usage seems less, it looks like the issue still persists. See results. First one using FETCH_INTO, second one using FETCH_CLASS.

**FETCH_INTO**
peak:2359296, 
**FETCH_CLASS**
peak:524288

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23308/discussion-between-martin-and-hek2mgl)

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [PHP changelog](http://uk.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.3.4), there does appear to be a relevant fix in 5.3.4 where a [memory leak was fixed in PDO `FETCH_INTO`](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52487).

From what you've said, I suspect that yes, this is the bug you're seeing. The solution, of course, is to upgrade -- there really is no point in sticking with an old patch release.

Even if this isn't the bug you're seeing, there have been a very large number of PDO fixes in the versions between 5.3.3 and now; I'm sure there's a good chance that at least some of them are relevant to you.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. guess its just the FETCH_INTO in the release I have. I'll have to try upgrade and check it out then. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: the original answer was given before the OP changed `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` to `PDO::FETCH_INTO`

After that update I've tried to reproduce the behaviour using `PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4`. There where no significant difference in memory cosumption between both fetch modes. I've tested using a large MySQL table and a large SQLite database.

As @SDC mentioned the bug is known and was fixed after 5.3.5. (At least in 5.3.10 as I've seen).

Conclusion: You have to **upgrade** your PHP version.

---

Although the behaviour is interesting and should be investigated you are using `PDO::setFetchMode()` in a wrong way. When $mode - the first param - is PDO::FETCH_OBJ **no** second param is expected. If you use a second param the call to `setFetchMode()` will fail (returnin false) and the default fetch mode `FETCH_BOTH` will be used.

You can see this error when enabling `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` :

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $db->query('....');

// the following line will trigger an exception
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ, new Company());
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: fetch mode doesn't allow any extra arguments'

When you are expecting that result rows should objects of a specific class, then `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` is the working attempt. `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` will return objects from type `StdClass`

Comment: Sorry, I had put the wrong code in.. Its not PDO::FETCH_OBJ, what I have is PDO::FETCH_INTO. Question still remains. I've edited my post

Comment: @Martin Ok, will further investigate. Currently browsing pdo_stmt.c :)

Answer (score 0):

FETCH_INTO: Means fetching into an existing Object (that was created with new e.g.)

FETCH_CLASS: Means fetching into an new Object (the constructor is called every row)

Be careful, if the constructor in your Company class has dependencies, they are called for every row. Therefore the constructor should not contain functions or classes that do an DB connect e.g. only simple initializing...

How does your Company class look like?

Comment: Ok think the difference comes from the line: $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_INTO, new Company()); if you are calling $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "Company"); PHP has to determine and create the class, in the first case it there allright.